# Skewed image - Not able to detect horizontal lines using CV2

Tags: opencv, python

In this image I am trying to detect horizontal lines. The code works well when image is not skewed. However, it is not working on such skewed images. I have tried this method to detect the right angle by histogram but many times is actually making it more skewed - [python-opencv-skew-correction-for-ocr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57964634/python-opencv-skew-correction-for-ocr)

[image: Skewed image]

Below is code to detect horizontal lines:

```
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(img_final_bin,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (100,1))
    thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    detected_lines = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
    cnts, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(detected_lines, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


    boundingBoxes = [list(cv2.boundingRect(c)) for c in cnts]
```

Below is the code for skew correction, which is giving wrong results to me:

```
def correct_skew(image, delta=0.001, limit=3):
    def determine_score(arr, angle):
        data = inter.rotate(arr, angle, reshape=False, order=0)
        histogram = np.sum(data, axis=1)
        score = np.sum((histogram[1:] - histogram[:-1]) ** 2)
        return histogram, score

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1] 

    print("thresh", thresh.shape)
    thresh1 = thresh[0:500, 0:500]
    print("thresh1", thresh1.shape)

    scores = []
    angles = np.arange(-limit, limit + delta, delta)
    for i, angle in enumerate(angles):
        histogram, score = determine_score(thresh1, angle)
        scores.append(score)
        # if i%100 == 0:   
        #     print(score, angle, len(angles), i)

    best_angle = angles[scores.index(max(scores))]

    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    center = (w // 2, h // 2)
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, best_angle, 1.0)
    rotated = cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (w, h), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, \
              borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)

    return best_angle, rotated
```

Comment: How about taking an image of some perfectly horizontal text and lines, rotating it through a few known angles and seeing what result you get from the algorithm and how the corrected version compares to the original?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this.. i have tried this on many variations.. few times it has given good results but most of times it fails.... I am looking for some better skew correction algo , or if this is correct the what is mistake in this...   If someone has experience on such issues, then they can try the image I have attached

Comment: Maybe if the skew angle is 17, you need to rotate by -17 as the correction? I'm guessing, obviously, but I am sure some testing will help.

Comment: the skew angle returned by above code is incorrect.. for example the image i have shown above is actually the output of this algo,, origionally it was little skewed now it is more skewed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python Wand, which is based upon ImageMagick has a deskew function.

Input:

[image]

```
from wand.image import Image
from wand.display import display

with Image(filename='table.png') as img:
    img.deskew(0.4*img.quantum_range)
    img.save(filename='table_deskew.png')
    display(img)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks.. it seem to work on this image... but would it work on other images too or the threshold 0.4*img.quantum_range is customized for this image only?

Comment: The threshold of 0.4*img.quantum_range is typical value use for almost all images, especially of black text on white background. However, if there is too few lines of text, it may not work too well. The more rows of text the better.

Comment: Do you know the actual *"units"* of what the threshold represents please, Fred? 40% of what?

Comment: Mark, no I do not. It is some internal threshold value in a radon transformation. You would have to look at the code to see how it is being used.