# "Newbie" questions about PyTesseract OCR

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm working on an application that would extract information from invoices that the user takes a picture of with his phone (using flask and pytesseract).

Everything works on the extraction and classification side for my needs, using the `image_to_data` method of pytesseract.

But the problem is on the pre-processing side.
I refine the image with greyscale filters, binarization, dilation, etc.
But sometimes the user will take a picture that has a specific angle, like this:
[invoice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oK0Y.png)

And then tesseract will return characters that don't make sense, or sometimes it will just return nothing.

At the moment I "scan" the image during pre-processing (I'm largely inspired by this tutorial: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/01/build-kick-ass-mobile-document-scanner-just-5-minutes/), but it's not efficient at all.

Does anyone know a way to make it easier for tesseract to work on these type of images?
If not, should I focus on making this pre-processing scan thing?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm finding the writing on that receipt hard to read myself.  Not sure if that's a thumbnail of the image you intend to process, or the actual user-submitted image.  If the former, I'd upload a full res image so people here can assist you.  If the latter, I'd probably request the user re-uploads with better resolution!  Regarding the angle, perhaps [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57964634/python-opencv-skew-correction-for-ocr) covers what you are trying to do?