# How to use PYZBAR to decode QR code OpenCV - Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, qr-code

I'm using python PYZBAR to decode QR code captured by real time cam.

```
decode(input_frame)
```

Naturally the output I get is as follows

```
[Decoded(data=b'DATA', type='QRCODE', rect=Rect(left=50, top=179, width=255, height=254), polygon=[Point(x=50, y=433), Point(x=305, y=424), Point(x=302, y=180), Point(x=51, y=179)], quality=1, orientation='UP')]
```

the output shows:

- The data stored in the QR Code.
- Code type (QRCODE).
- The position of each corner of the QR Code in the frame.
- Quality.
- And the orientation of the QR Code (whether it up, down, left or right).

I'm only concerned about the **data stored in the QR Code** and its **Orientation**

How can I define them as a variable to use them later, something like the following pseudo code:

```
x = orientation y = data stored in QR Code
if x == up && y == DATA:
...........
```

My goal is to read and decode QR Code data and orientation to navigate a robot like the video provided in the link.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DZe27aKX0kY

Answer (score 1):

solved the issue, this is the new code

```
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
import cv2
import serial
import time

arduino = serial.Serial(port='COM6', baudrate=115200, timeout=1)


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


def write_read(x):
    arduino.write(bytes(x, 'utf-8'))
    time.sleep(0.05)
    data = arduino.readline()
   return data


def get_qr_data(input_frame):
try:
    return decode(input_frame)
except:
    return []

while True:
_, frame = cap.read()
qr_obj = get_qr_data(frame)
try:
 data = qr_obj[0].data
 angle = qr_obj[0].orientation
 print(data)
 print(angle)
except IndexError:
 pass
cv2.imshow("DD", frame)

if qr_obj == get_qr_data(frame):
 arduino.write(b'O')

if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):

  break


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

You figured out a solution to your problem. Let me show you something that exists within OpenCV

OpenCV also has an in-built function to detect QR codes since version `4.x`. There is a dedicated module for this purpose `cv2.QRCodeDetector()`. It gives you:

- data associated with QR code
- location of it

You can also detect QR code on a curved surface using `cv2.QRCodeDetector().decodeCurved()`

And multiple QR codes in an image using `cv2.QRCodeDetector(). decodeMulti()`

To get more info on the same, type the following and execute

```
help(cv2.QRCodeDetector())
```

Also refer [this useful blog post](https://learnopencv.com/opencv-qr-code-scanner-c-and-python/)

Also refer [to this recent answer by Christoph Rackwitz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72051076/rotating-qr-code-to-the-correct-position-using-python-opencv/72055279#72055279)

Comment: I would just point out that it's not very reliable and not working very well. I did run into issues with detectMulti / decodeAndDetectMulti - which is almost not working at all and I have ended up training a detection model (on yolov8) and importing it to opencv for detecting the actual rectangles.